# MySQL query refinement on the fly

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE (`status` = 'red' OR `status` = 'orange') ORDER BY `$orderby` $ad");
```

The $orderby aspect has up until now been very simple - select a column name from the table and use that to order the results by. So far the options have been things like `lastModified` and `reference`

I have been asked to add an additional field into this as a potential choice, named `allocation` which is, annoyingly, a field that holds two parts of information and only one of these is actually desired for the order by process. Such options are either `null` or formatted: `16/02/2017 - Sydney` or `19/05/2017 - New York` and so on.

How can I strip everything so I can just order by the date which is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and discard the `- Location` stuff while within the query? I know how to do it in PHP but not directly in the MySQL query. Is it even possible? I'm guessing it is somehow... (hoping)!

Comment: Use `LOCATE()` to find the space, and `LEFT()` to grab everything up to that position.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: both comments above is correct, well, if Barmar's approach is too hard, grab some ORM. Tadman's comment is important if you don't use ORM.

Comment: Whenever possible put dates in a `DATE` field in [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so they can be sorted, indexed, and compared in a meaningful way. You can do any conversion for display by the user later, and at that point take into account things like the user's personal preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOCATE()` will return the position of the first space character, and `LEFT(str, n)` returns the first `n` characters of `str`.

```
ORDER BY LEFT(allocation, LOCATE(allocation, ' ')-1)
```

However, your dates aren't formatted well for ordering. `16/02/2017` will be ordered before `18/01/2017`. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse this into a date and then order by that.

Comment: Thak you Barmar, the system I am dealing with is legacy so I do not have control of what is right or wrong about it before now. Your solution seems to be working until I can go through and better organise the initial data structure.